# error when trying to submit form to database

Tags: sql, database, laravel

Hi so when I'm trying to submit my form to my database I get the following error

ERROR

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'urenregistratie.issues' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `issues` (`iname`, `begroting`, `description`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (test, 100, test description, 2019-12-04 09:19:54, 2019-12-04 09:19:54))
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'iname' => 'required',
            'begroting' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',

            ]);

            $issue = new Issue;

            $issue->iname = $request->input('iname');
            $issue->begroting = $request->input('begroting');
            $issue->description = $request->input('description');

            $issue->save();

            return redirect('/issue')->with('success', 'Data Saved');



    }
```

MIGRATION

```
   public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('issue', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('iname');
            $table->time('begroting');
            $table->mediumText('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('issue');
    }
}
```

Urenregistratie is my database name. but I don't know where its getting the issues from since I called it issue without the S
so where is it getting the issues from

if I'm missing anything code wise if I do let me know.

Comment: Laravel assumes your table name is the plural form of your model name. That's by default. So it adds an "s" to all your model name to create your table for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your migration creates **issue** table but you're saving to **issues** table. Check your table name in the model class.

```
class Issue extends Model
{
protected $table = 'issue'; // this table name
.
.
.
}
```